# openapi-core result to weird implementation?

Tags: python-requests, openapi

I'm trying to use openapi-core Requests integration to validate response against an openapi spec file (generated by fastAPI and compliant with openApi 3.1.0).
I'm using openapi-core version 0.18.2 and python version 3.10.
And the results are a bit weird, to says the least.

My code:

```
class RestManager:
    def __init__(self, mgr, component) -> None:
        self.mgr = mgr
        self.openApi = None
        self.certs_file = None
        self.COMMAND = {}
        self.MONITORING = {}
        self.component = component
        self.oa_validation = True

        # open api spec validation
        section = mgr.config[f'REST_{component}']
        self.protocol = section['protocol']
        self.url = f"{self.protocol}://{section[f'server']}:{section[f'port']}"

        if mgr.config.has_option(f'REST_{component}', 'oa_validation'):
            self.oa_validation = section['oa_validation'] == 'true'

        if self.oa_validation and mgr.config.has_option(f'REST_{component}', 'openapi_file'):
            oa_file = section[f'openapi_file']
            if len(oa_file) > 0:
                spec_dict = None
                try:
                    spec_dict, base_uri = read_from_filename(oa_file)
                except FileNotFoundError as e:
                    logger.warning(f'Unable to load openapi file: {e}')
                except PermissionError as e:
                    logger.warning(f'Unable to access openapi file: {e}')
                if spec_dict is not None:
                    try:
                        openapi_spec_validator.validate(spec_dict)
                        logger.info(f'{oa_file} is a valid Openapi file')
                        self.openApi = OpenAPI.from_file_path(oa_file)
                    except OpenAPIValidationError as e:
                        logger.warning(f'Unable to validate openapi file: {oa_file} {e}')
                    except ValidatorDetectError as e:
                        logger.warning(f'Unable to validate openapi file: {oa_file} {e}')

        # https
        if mgr.config.has_option('REST', 'certs_file'):
            self.certs_file = mgr.config.get('REST', 'certs_file')

    # post
    def request(self, method, url, kwargs):
        logger.debug(f'params: {kwargs}')
        json = None
        params = None
        headers = None
        files = None
        data = None
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            if key == 'json':
                json = kwargs[key]
            elif key == 'params':
                # to handle colon in params (startDate, endDate, ...)
                params = urllib.parse.urlencode(kwargs[key], safe=':+')
            elif key == 'headers':
                headers = kwargs[key]
            elif key == 'files':
                files = kwargs[key]
            elif key == 'data':
                data = kwargs[key]
        r = None
        try:
            r = requests.request(method, url,
                                  headers=headers,
                                  json=json,
                                  params=params,
                                  files=files,
                                  data=data,
                                  verify=self.certs_file)
        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            logger.error(f'{e}')
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            logger.error(f'{e}')
        except urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError as e:
            logger.error(f'{e}')
        except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema as e:
            logger.error(f'{e}')
        return r

    # post
    def post_request(self, url, **kwargs):
        return self.request('POST', url, kwargs)

    # put
    def put_request(self, url, **kwargs):
        return self.request('PUT', url, kwargs)

    # get
    def get_request(self, url, **kwargs):
        return self.request('GET', url, kwargs)

    # delete
    def delete_request(self, url, **kwargs):
        return self.request('DELETE', url, kwargs)

    def validate(self, response) -> bool:
        res = True
        if self.oa_validation is True:
            try:
                oa_request = RequestsOpenAPIRequest(response.request)
                oa_response = RequestsOpenAPIResponse(response)
                self.openApi.validate_response(oa_request, oa_response)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f'{e}')
        return res

    def get_command_attribute(self, attribute):
        val = self.COMMAND[attribute]
        return val

    def get_monitored_attribute(self, attribute):
        val = self.MONITORING[attribute]
        return val

    def get_commands_attributes(self):
        return self.COMMAND

    def get_monitored_attributes(self):
        return [self.MONITORING]

    def get_formatted(self, attributes: list):
        res = []
        for attribute in attributes:
            if attribute in self.MONITORING.keys():
                res.append(self.MONITORING[attribute])
            elif attribute in self.COMMAND.keys():
                res.append(self.COMMAND[attribute])
            else:
                logger.error(f'unknown attribute : {attribute}')
        return res

    def get_http_error_message(self):
        logger.error(f'{self.protocol} connection error')

    @staticmethod
    def get_failed_validation_message(r):
        logger.warning(f"Failed open api validation: "
                       f"code {r.status_code}, method {r.request.method}, "
                       f"url {r.request.url}, "
                       f"content {r.content}")

    @staticmethod
    def get_unexpected_code_message(r):
        logger.warning(f"Unexpected code: {r.status_code}, "
                       f"method {r.request.method}, "
                       f"url {r.request.url}, "
                       f"content {r.content}")

    @staticmethod
    def get_success_message(r):
        logger.info(f'Successful request code {r.request.method} for {r.request.url} ')

    def process_request(self, r, expected_codes: list, process_function, *args):
        res = None
        if r is not None:
            if self.validate(r) is True:
                if r.status_code in expected_codes:
                    res = process_function(r, args)
                else:
                    self.get_unexpected_code_message(r)
            else:
                self.get_failed_validation_message(r)
        else:
            self.get_http_error_message()
        return res

    def process_set_commands(self, r, args):
        self.get_success_message(r)

    def set_commands(self, command_values: list, log=False):
        end_point = f'/controls'
        command_values_rest = {}
        for (command, value) in command_values:
            command_values_rest.update({command: value})
        r = self.post_request(f"{self.url}{end_point}", json=command_values_rest)
        self.process_request(r, [200], process_function=self.process_set_commands)

    def process_control(self, r, args):
        self.COMMAND = r.json()
        logger.debug('COMMAND:', self.COMMAND)

    def control(self):
        end_point = f'/controls'
        r = self.get_request(f"{self.url}{end_point}")
        self.process_request(r, [200], process_function=self.process_control)

    def process_monitoring(self, r, args):
        self.MONITORING = r.json()
        logger.debug('MONITORING:', self.MONITORING)

    def monitoring(self):
        end_point = '/monitoring'
        r = self.get_request(f"{self.url}{end_point}")
        self.process_request(r, [200], process_function=self.process_monitoring)

    @staticmethod
    def process_json(r, args):
        res = r.json()
        return res

    def get_last_logs(self):
        end_point = '/last_logs'
        r = self.get_request(f"{self.url}{end_point}")
        res = self.process_request(r, [200], process_function=self.process_json)
        return res
```

The openapi file content is:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "FastAPI",
    "version": "0.1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/last_logs": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get Last Logs",
        "description": "retrieve last logs",
        "operationId": "get_last_logs_last_logs_get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Log"
                  },
                  "type": "array",
                  "title": "Response Get Last Logs Last Logs Get"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/monitoring": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Monitoring",
        "description": "retrieve monitoring list",
        "operationId": "monitoring_monitoring_get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Monitoring"
                  },
                  "type": "array",
                  "title": "Response Monitoring Monitoring Get"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/controls": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get Controls",
        "description": "retrieve controls",
        "operationId": "get_controls_controls_get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Controls"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "summary": "Set Controls",
        "description": "set controls. Null fields are ignored.",
        "operationId": "set_controls_controls_put",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Controls"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {}
              }
            }
          },
          "422": {
            "description": "Validation Error",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HTTPValidationError"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Controls": {
        "properties": {
          "frequency": {
            "type": "number",
            "title": "Frequency"
          },
          "power": {
            "type": "number",
            "title": "Power"
          },
          "emit": {
            "type": "integer",
            "title": "Emit"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "frequency",
          "power",
          "emit"
        ],
        "title": "Controls"
      },
      "HTTPValidationError": {
        "properties": {
          "detail": {
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ValidationError"
            },
            "type": "array",
            "title": "Detail"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "title": "HTTPValidationError"
      },
      "Level": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "none",
          "unknown",
          "info",
          "warning",
          "error"
        ],
        "title": "Level"
      },
      "Log": {
        "properties": {
          "level": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Level"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time",
            "title": "Date"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Text"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "level",
          "date",
          "text"
        ],
        "title": "Log"
      },
      "Monitoring": {
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Key"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Name"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Value"
          },
          "alarmLevel": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Level"
          },
          "alarmDate": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Alarm Date"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Text"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "key",
          "name",
          "value",
          "alarmLevel",
          "AlarmDate",
          "text"
        ],
        "title": "Monitoring"
      },
      "ValidationError": {
        "properties": {
          "loc": {
            "items": {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              ]
            },
            "type": "array",
            "title": "Location"
          },
          "msg": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Message"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Error Type"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "loc",
          "msg",
          "type"
        ],
        "title": "ValidationError"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then create an instance of RestMAnager and receives no error while verifying spec of the open_api file (content above).

1/ first weird result:

When I query the server '/monitoring' end point (path) with get method, the server replies OK (status code 200) with the following json body:
{"emit": 1, "frequency": "1560000000.0", "power": "-10.0"}.
The "validate" method of RestManager logs the following message :
2024-01-09 11:24:00,025    ERROR restManager line 125 validate 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'.
If I withdraw the catch mechanism in RestManager.validate method, I logically receive the same final message but with a more precise exception error (AttributeError) as described below:
File "/home/ats/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openapi_core/casting/schemas/casters.py", line 80, in validate
if value.lower() not in ["false", "true"]:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'.

Of course, when the server sends a boolen value instead of an integer value, there is no exception.

I expected to receive a message displaying a DataValidationError error indicating at least which  property is involved, as would do 'jsonschema' python module.
I've implemented low level as described at https://openapi-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations/requests.html and I got the same results.

2/ Other weird result:

When I query /monitoring end point (path) with get method, the server replies OK (status code 200) with the following json body:
{'alarmDate': '2024-01-09T09-57:42.00Z', 'alarmLevel': 1, 'key': 'STATUS', 'name': 'global status', 'text': '', 'value': ''}.

The RestManager.validate method logs the following message:
2024-01-09 11:24:00,025    ERROR restManager line 125 validate DataValidationError: Failed to cast value to object type: alarmDate
Normally a proper jsonschema validator should indicate an error with the fact that an array is expected or the wrong alarmLevel property type... .
I've also implemented low level as described at [https://openapi-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations/requests.html] and I got the same result.

Am I doing something wrong ?!